# How should I go along to design a web forum?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

im pretty new to web development and I thought about doing a project where I designed a basic web forum. Is there anyway someone could point me in the right direction or how I should go along with it? My current stack is vue2, express, mongodb with passport for authentication. Is it possible/manageable with this stack? or are there some new technologies I should pick up?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with any stack. This is such a general question that it's really hard to answer anything meaningful. This is a nice goal to learn your tech stack so go for it. You can use any language, any framework and any database to make a forum so I can only say that yes, it's possible.

To answer the second part of your question on how you should go along with that then well, try to learn your stack as much as you can, read a lot of documentation and if you get stuck then first try to search for question asked here by other people and if you have a problem that was not discussed before then post a new question with a short example of code that can reproduce the problem, information what you have tried and what errors did you have.

The most important is: start coding first, ask questions second.